# How to have multiple versions of the same package as the indirect dependencies of a project?

Tags: java, maven, elasticsearch, neo4j, lucene

I'm working on a project which connects to Elasticsearch 5.2.1 and Neo4j 3.1.0 at the same time. These two packages both make use of Lucene but unfortunately incompatible versions. Elaticseach needs Lucence 6.4.1 and Neo4j works with Lucene 5.5.0.

As the result, I'm facing with runtime errors since some of the classes have incompatible signatures. Is there any way I can have both Elasticsearch and Neo4j (with the given versions) in one project?

What I'm trying to do is to add Elasticsearch package to [this project](https://github.com/graphaware/neo4j-framework/blob/master/examples/friendship-strength-counter-module/pom.xml). And here are the Elasticsearch dependencies that I added:

```
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch</groupId>
        <artifactId>elasticsearch</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
    <dependency>
        <groupId>org.elasticsearch.client</groupId>
        <artifactId>transport</artifactId>
        <version>5.2.1</version>
    </dependency>
```

How can I make these two to play alongside of each other nicely?

Comment: not possible from what I know. You can use some version of both of these which have compatible versions of Lucene.

Comment: But I need latest versions of both!!!

Comment: Are you really need to have them into a single project which contains only a single pom file?

Comment: @khmarbaise I've updated the question with what I'm trying to do because to be honest I'm not sure I understand your question.

Answer (score 0):

Each combination of jar should be packaged inside a distinct jar with dependencies  or a war and these should not share the same parent classloader so that a loaded class that exits in two distinct versions of the jar with dependencies  or a war be  loaded by a distinct classloader.

Comment: Could you please show me how can I implement your solution?